# How to specify bounds and variable length in python union types?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a type that has subclasses.  E.g., `Event`, with classes `Event1(Event)`, `Event2(Event)`, etc.  I want to specify a type annotation for the argument to a function that accepts any union of subclasses of `Event`.  Concretely, I want all of the following to type check:

```py
listen_for_events(Event1)
listen_for_events(Event1 | Event3)
listen_for_events(Event1 | Event2 | Event3)
```

while the following should *not* type check:

```py
listen_for_events(str | int)
```

How do I specify the type on the argument to `listen_for_events`?  I can do this with `tuple` (`tuple[type[Event], ...]`), but I don't appear to be able to do something similar with `Union`.  Is there a way to correctly type this?

Comment: The function can accept "any union of subclasses of `Event`"? Then why doesn't it just accept... `Event`?

Comment: Notice that it's not `listen_for_events(Event1())`, it's `listen_for_events(Event1)`.  To handle one type, you would do `def listen_for_events(event_type: type[Event])` (or use a type var with `bound=Event`). To handle multiple event types, you do `def listen_for_events(event_types: ???)`.

Comment: Also note: an alternative design would be to accept `type[Event] | tuple[type[Event], ...]`, instead of using a union for this, which is arguably the better design in this case. But the question still stands for other cases where you really do want to have this union.

Comment: Oh, you're doing a metaprogramming type thing. I'm still not clear on why it makes sense to set things up so that something else will listen for events that are of specific subtypes; but I can at least imagine designs like that. Did you consider using a metaclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer this question, firstly let's look at how union types work. The syntax you're describing generates a `types.UnionType`, and you can't specify any more detail about this type. e.g. Something like the below passes for all of your examples, including the one you didn't want:

```py
def listen_for_events(event: type[Event] | types.UnionType):
    ...

listen_for_events(Event1)
listen_for_events(Event1 | Event2 | Event3)
listen_for_events(str | int)
```

### Why does python not offer a more descriptive syntax for this?

Consider the features of the collection of events. What the union syntax is really expressing here is we want to be able to supply:

- an unknown number of events
- in no particular order
- with no repeats

...or in other words, a `set`:

```py
def listen_for_events(event: set[type[Event]]):
    ...

listen_for_events({Event1})
listen_for_events({Event1, Event2, Event3})
listen_for_events({str, int}) # raises error
```

*Note: for this to work you have to make event hashable, or use `frozenset`*

This is actually more than a coincidence - in some sense a union of objects is just a way of expressing the specific members in a particular set. `A | B` is the set that contains only A and B, it's just that normally in python we ascribe this set to a type and say:

*"x must be an instance of the class that features in the set `A | B`"*

### Is there a better syntax?

If we relax the unordered and non-repeating condition, which maybe is not so critical to the problem, there become other options available (including the tuple mentioned in the comments). Personally I think the best syntax for the problem you're trying to solve would be the below:

```py
def listen_for_events(*events: type[Event]):
    ...

listen_for_events(Event1)
listen_for_events(Event1, Event2, Event3)
listen_for_events(str, int) # raises error
```

An advantage of this syntax is it even flags the exact member that differs from the type if you entered something like: `listen_for_events(str, Event1)`

In summary, python may not offer an exact way to type the syntax you want, but it does off other structures that express exactly the same concept. Hope this is useful!

Comment: Note that `Event` _instances_ do not need to hashable for the syntax `{Event1, Event2, Event3}` to work, only `Event` _types_ (which they are by default, you only need to worry about that if `Event` uses a custom metaclass that explicitly makes them unhashable).

Comment: In principle there isn't a reason that you _couldn't_ have, e.g., `Union[EventT, ...]`, like we do for `tuple`, is there?  (Where `EventT = TypeVar("EventT", bound=Event)`.)  It's just that python's type system hasn't implemented this (yet)?

Comment: It would have to be `UnionType[EventT, ...]`, but regardless objects in python should have distinct uses. The point I was making here is that `UnionType[EventT, ...]` would be exactly the same object as `set[EventT]`, even if it has a different syntax.

Comment: I suppose the real issue here is that the object `X | Y` is not intended to be used at runtime (that's why it converts to `UnionType` from the `types` library). But `{X,Y}` is an exactly equivalent object that is intended to be used at runtime, so there's no lack of feature here.

Comment: The "is not intended to be used at runtime" bit is a bit confusing to me - PEP 604 adds syntax for `isinstance(x, str | int)`, and linters have rules that recommend this usage.  If I want to take an input argument to some function that will then be used in a call to `isinstance(x, my_type)`, how do I type that argument, with specific bounds on the union? That's the question, and it doesn't seem like it's an unintended usage, given PEP 604.